# find xpath using regular expression

Tags: regex

Suppose I have this as an XPath:

```
//*[@id="view-id-latest_news-page_3"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a
```

What and how could I do to get all the XPath that is in this format:

```
//*[@id="view-id-latest_news-page_3"]/div/div[1]/div[1-9]/div[1]/a
```

I think using regular expression is probably the easiest way but I am not sure how to do.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?  How do you know which `/div[1]` you want to change to `/div[1-9]`?  Language?

Comment: Do you mean `div[1]` the entire line, then `div[2]`, 3, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
//\*\[@id="view-id-latest_news-page_3"]/div/div\[1]/div\[1-9]/div\[1]/a
```